# Visudo permission in file execute script

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, php

I'm trying to run a shell script via php but I'm getting a permission error, however I'm trying to add permission to my www-data user to use the sudo command without a password, but it's not working, I don't know if I'm reporting anything wrong. Below is how my "visudo" file is edited.

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/mysite/classes/MyClassToCallScript.php
```

My code PHP is:

```php
$command = "sudo sh ".dirname(__FILE__)."/builder-sites-nginx.sh {$domain}";
// dump($command);
$response = shell_exec($command);
```

My code Shell:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_FROM=/etc/nginx/sites-available/sites-builders
FILE_TO=/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/"$1"

[ ! -d "$FILE_FROM" ] && mkdir -p "$FILE_FROM"

if test -f "$FILE_TO"; then
    echo "syntax is ok. $FILE_TO already exists"
else
        ln -s "$FILE_FROM/$1" /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

        #check stats
        if nginx -t > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                echo "syntax is ok"
                service nginx reload
        else
                echo "syntax is not ok"
                rm "$FILE_TO"
        fi
fi
```

But my response is "empty".
I did a test by adding the following excerpt to my "visudo"

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Using the way I mentioned above works, but I believe that the security of my site will be at risk, correct? Why my apache user will have sudo permissions and if someone puts in some malicious file I will be in trouble, so I come back with my initial question, the way I am putting the path to "visudo" in just executing the given script is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not running `sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh`, you're running `sudo sh /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh` - and `sudo` isn't configured to allow www-data to run `sudo sh` (and nor should it be - that would be an enormous security hole, equivalent to `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`).

Make `/var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh` executable with `chmod +x`, and make sure that it has `#!/bin/bash` as the first line (`#!/bin/sh` would work too because your script doesn't use any bash-only features).

Then modify your PHP code to:

```
$command = "sudo ".dirname(__FILE__)."/builder-sites-nginx.sh {$domain}";
```

BTW, depending on where and how `$domain` was defined (i.e. if it came from user-supplied data), you may need to use PHP's `escapeshellcmd()` function to sanitise it.

Comment: thanks to answer, I made the changes as you suggested, I added the permission chmod +x in the file builder-sites-nginx.sh and change my php, but when I run php it is returning "null" in the response from shell_exec, and should return some text, as if syntax is ok or not. Print return: https://prnt.sc/12plwv7

Comment: does it run from the command line?  e.g. `sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash` to get a shell as www-data, followed by `sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh`

Comment: if I understand correctly, is it to do a test like this? ```sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh ``` ? IF it is, I did it and it didn't work... I make a test using on terminal: ```sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh``` but not working too.. my response is: ```sudo: ....builder-sites-nignx.sh: command not found```, thanks for help again!

Comment: That was two commands.  1. `sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash`.  This gives you a shell as user `www-data`. 2. Next, try to run the script with `sudo` while in the `www-data` shell, `sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh`.   You could do it as one command with `sudo -u www-data sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh`.      Anyway, if the script doesn't run with sudo from the command line, it's a problem with the script, not sudo.

Comment: BTW, you almost certainly don't need (and **shouldn't** have) `..../MyClassToCallScript.php` executable via sudo.  You only need the shell script that it calls, `...../builder-sites-nginx.sh`, to be run as root by www-data.

Comment: thanks again for your help.. I make a test using: ```sudo -u www-data -s /bin/bash``` but have a error with response: ```bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied```, my second test using command: ```sudo -u www-data sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh``` my response is: ```www-data is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.```. About the last comment I use a PHP because is necessary a action from my user in front end page. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: 1. I understand you use php.  That doesn't mean the .php script itself needs to be listed in /etc/sudoers (it almost certainly shouldn't be, because you don't/shouldn't need to run the .php script as root).   2. If www-data is not in the sudoers file, you must have changed it since you posted your question.  You need to fix that, so that www-data is allowed to run `/var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh` as root.

Comment: 3. the /root/.bashrc error message shouldn't be happening.  It sounds like a warning message and can probably be ignored until you get this working.  If it's more serious, it's a different problem and needs a new question.

Comment: I'm sorry, I really changed it after your first comment, I understood that with chmod + x there would be no need for permission in the visudo .. I added again: ```www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh
``` after added again in visudo the user, my response to command ```sudo -u www-data sudo /var......``` was it : ```Sorry, user www-data is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/sudo /var/www/mysite/classes/builder-sites-nginx.sh'```

Comment: /etc/sudoers is what sudo uses to decide if a user is allowed to run a program as root (or as some other user).   Without a matching entry, sudo refuses.    In this case, www-data isn't allowed to run `sudo`.   That's why I had two separate commands (assuming that the first sudo would be run as root).     You can try it as two commands.  Or (definitely **not** recommended), temporarily allow www-data to run `/usr/bin/sudo` while testing, but remember to delete that rule when you've finished testing.   It's much easier (and safer) to just use the two commands.

Comment: Now I understand correctly the 2 separate commands ..
Anyway, I used the 2 separate commands that you mentioned at the beginning and it worked .. I did it as follows: https://prnt.sc/12rc5l0, It's works. One last question, the way that I left the permission in the "visudo" is I at risk of having a security breach?

Comment: I have no idea because I don't know what's in your /etc/sudoers file.   Also, [Please don't post images of text or, worse, links to pictures of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).  Copy and paste the text itself **into your question** and format it as code by selecting it and pressing Ctrl-K or by using the editor's `{}` icon.